# How to fix "attempt to index nil with"

Tags: button, roblox

I am trying to make a button which is a part to teleport you once pressed but when it is pressed it says: attempt to index nil with 'HummanoidRootPart'

I can't find anything on how to fix my problem specifically.

```
function click(x)
    local y = workspace:FindFirstChild(x).HumanoidRootPart.CFrame
    local location = script.Parent.Location.Position
    y = CFrame.new(location)
    print("Teleported")
end

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(click)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Where it says "workspace:FindFirstChild(x)", workspace can't find the first child called "x". You used x as a parameter to find in the workspace, which doesn't make sense because workspace:FindFirstChild finds objects by name. Workspace can't find the child with the name "x", or workspace returns nil because it tries to find something that is not a string, so it returns "nil" which is "nil.HumanoidRootPart" which is not allowed.

Consider doing this

```lua
function click()
    local y = workspace:FindFirstChild("nameOfObjectYouWantToFind").HumanoidRootPart.CFrame
    local location = script.Parent.Location.Position
    y = CFrame.new(location)
    print("Teleported")
end

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(click)
```

Remember to change "nameOfObjectYouWantToFind" to the name of the thing you want to find.

Comment: in their code, `x` becomes the Player that interacted with the ClickDetector. See the docs for the [MouseClick event](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/ClickDetector#MouseClick). It's highly likely that they are trying to get the Player's Character model in the workspace. So a better fix might be `function click(player) local y= player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.Name` at the end beacause `FindFirstChild()` checks for strings

```
function click(player)
    local y = workspace:FindFirstChild(player.Name).HumanoidRootPart.CFrame
    local location = script.Parent.Location.Position
    y = CFrame.new(location)
    print("Teleported")
end

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(click)
```